# Conditional blocking with ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: java, threadpoolexecutor

I want to extend `ThreadPoolExecutor` to not only block if the maximum thread count has been reached but also on a separate condition which I could set. I'm not sure how to go about this, or if it is even possible.

It looks like providing a ThreadFactory that won't create a thread if the condition is set *might* be the way to go, but I'm not exactly sure if that is the best approach. Could it be possible that there was an extra thread not being used after the flag was set so the factory didn't need to be used and therefore my operation isn't placed in a que but gets to run?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think extending a `ThreadPoolExecutor` will be that complicated. [The JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) give an example. I'm also fairly certain that the executor is the place to extend. I believe that a `ThreadFactory` is a slightly higher-level way of producing new threads. It's the executor that decides when to make them.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still not sure, it seems all of the methods having to do with blocking are final/private making extending for my purposes complicated if even possible.

Comment: While not ideal and under most circumstances I wouldn't recommend it, you could just copy _ThreadPoolExecutor_ into your own project and adjust it as you see fit. As you would be creating your _SchwizTPE_ directly from Java source, you would need to release your project with a GPL-compatible license.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to look at

http://code.google.com/p/disruptor/

this does almost what you are looking for.

Comment: the link provided is dead